# Android listener between fragments

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment

I have a fragment that shows a another fragment taking up half screen by clicking a button and I am passing a listener with it

```
 //Fragment that shows inside another fragment

public View onCreateView....{
newUserFragment = NewUserFragment.newInstance(onCreatedUser);

}

 ListContract.OnCreatedUser onCreatedUser = new ListContract.OnCreatedUser() {
    @Override
    public void OnSuccess(User user) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "user: " + user.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

//NewUserFragment

public static NewUserFragment newInstance (ListContract.OnCreatedUser onCreatedUser){
    NewUserFragment newUserFragment = new NewUserFragment();
    newUserFragment.onCreatedUser = onCreatedUser;
    return new NewUserFragment();
}

saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            User user = new User(userEt.getText().toString(),dateTxt.getText()+"T"+timeTxt.getText());
            onCreatedUser.OnSuccess(user);
            int i = 1;
        }
    });
```

I have done this before and I actually do the same with DatePickerFragment & TimePickerFragment from Android, I am getting a null pointer and I don't know why.

Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.helloworldexercise.ui.list.ListContract$OnCreatedUser.OnSuccess(com.helloworldexercise.data.entity.User)' on a null object reference
                      at com.helloworldexercise.ui.newuser.NewUserFragment$3.onClick(NewUserFragment.java:85)

85: onCreatedUser.OnSuccess(user);

[image: First Fragment]

[image: FirstFragment showing NewUserFragment]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably want to take another look at your `newInstance` method:

```
public static NewUserFragment newInstance (ListContract.OnCreatedUser onCreatedUser){
    NewUserFragment newUserFragment = new NewUserFragment();
    newUserFragment.onCreatedUser = onCreatedUser;
    return new NewUserFragment();
}
```

You set the listener, but then return a new object.  See if this change doesn't solve your problem:

```
public static NewUserFragment newInstance (ListContract.OnCreatedUser onCreatedUser){
    NewUserFragment newUserFragment = new NewUserFragment();
    newUserFragment.onCreatedUser = onCreatedUser;
    return newUserFragment;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, my mistake. I can't believe i was an hour checking everything instead of this. :D